# Disable image compression for WebP

Tags: images

The following function disables image compression:

```
add_filter( 'wp_editor_set_quality', function( $arg ) {
    return 100;
});
```

Does this cover WebP images as well as JPEGs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does cover webp as well. From several google pages the default compression was 86.  You could also test to confirm by uploading a few with different settings in your functions.
This issue on Github shows they changed the default quality to 82.
https://github.com/WordPress/performance/issues/563.

We can see that webp images use the same quality value as jpeg images [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/0cb8475c0d07d23893b1d73d755eda5f12024585/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php#L547).